# In hibernate 3.6.8, what do I use instead of nullSafeSet and nullSafeGet since the docs say they are deprecated

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I was creating a custom user type a few minutes ago, when I looked at the javadocs and saw that `nullSafeSet()` and `nullSafeGet` are deprecated. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html I don't see any other way implementing my `UserType`. Was this maybe just meant for the 4.0 release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Jira issue referenced from the documentation](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5968) makes for interesting reading. I've only skimmed it, but it sounds like this is mostly a "heads-up: we're going to change things in Hibernate 4" warning more than anything else.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot Hibernate likes to implement that deprecate-with-no-alternative pattern.

Comment: What about the various nullSafeSet methods that take a SessionImplementor?  Is there some way we're supposed to use THAT?  And if so, where do I get one of these SessionImplementors in my custom UserType?